# Toastr: How to prevent fade out with sticky toast on mouseover?

Tags: notifications, mouseover, message, sticky, toastr

I've been playing with toastr and have successfully set the timeout to 0 so the toast remains sticky, however the toast disappears when I mouse out of the toast.  I'd like to override this so the toast only goes away if the user clicks it - ideal for toasts with lots of text.  How can this be done?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Set `extendedTimeOut` to 0 too. That will keep it sticky.

Comment: I'm really enjoying `Toastr` in a current project. Thanks John for all the work you give away to the community.

Comment: This seems to be case sensitive:
`        "timeOut": "0",
        "extendedTimeOut": "0"`

Comment: @JohnPapa - I'm heavily using toastr in my project, its awesome. I'm facing one issue with sticky toastr. Could you please help me with how I can close a sticky toastr? I have a button in the sticky toast and I want to close the toast once user click on that button. In the button click event I have used ' toastr.options.timeOut = 5;' but the toastr is not disappearing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `timeout` also needs to be set to `0`!!

Answer (score 29):

`timeOut` and `extendedTimeOut` must be set to `0`.

Here is a complete example:

```
toastr.options = {
    timeOut: 0,
    extendedTimeOut: 0
};

toastr.info("Testing <button>blah</button>");
```

For those who wish to not close the toast on click, the example changes to:

```
toastr.options = {
    timeOut: 0,
    extendedTimeOut: 0,
    tapToDismiss: false
};

toastr.info("Testing <button>blah</button>");
```

Comment: Thanks for `TapToDismiss`. But now, if I want to set `timeOut: 5000`, `extendedTimeOut: 0` will not work anymore. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

you could also use `disableTimeOut` as an alternative to setting both `timeOut` and `extendedTimeOut` to 0.

```
toastr.options = {
    disableTimeOut : true, //Equivalent ot timeOut: 0 and extendedTimeOut: 0
}
```

Comment: I could not find any reference to `disableTimeOut`